# Telling the Difference between two Android GUI objects with the same ID

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Say we have two XML files, of which these are snippets:

`firstxml.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/button1 />
```

`secondxml.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/button1 />
```

In our `onCreate()` method:

```
//Assume all packages necessary are imported
public class Example
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle sis)
    {
      super.onCreate(sis);
      setContentView(R.layout.firstxml);

      Button thisButton = (Button) findViewbyId(R.id.button1);

    }
}
```

Which button is called and instantiated when this code runs? Since the two buttons are in two different files, will the button in `firstxml.xml` be called because it is the content view of the function?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing the the first XML layout file `R.layout.firstxml` in the activity's `onCreate(Bundle...)` method, so the search here will be made.

Any call to `findViewById(int id);` will search in your inflated layout `R.layout.firstxml`.

The `R.java` file is automatically generated when you are defining/adding a new view to your layout.

You can use the same id multiple times, but **not in the same layout** !

Answer (score 2):

When you set the firstxml to be the content view, that layout gets inflated. findViewById will find the id's in the current layout that's inflated rather than on every layout.

[setContentView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(android.view.View)) method description kind of answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

The code will call and instantiate the button1 set on your firstxml.xml file.

**Note** For future readers. If the layout file doesnot contain button1 it will throw null pointer exception and the editor wont know that there is an error. This is because **R.id.button1** is static field in your R.java class. Also provide better naming convention to your variables for maintainability.

Answer (score 1):

```
Which button is called and instantiated when this code runs?
```

Since you used the `firstxml.xml` as the layout of the activity you are calling the reference of that button from that xml not the button from the `secondxml.xml`.

And in your R.java it will only generate one instance of that id.

**sample:**

```
public static final class id {
    public static final int button1=0x7f090009;
}
```

so when you used that reference of that button it will first find/check the layout's id if it exist if it does not exist then it will throw **NPE**.